# is it a good idea to use "sudo bash -c" instead of "sudo" always?

Tags: linux, bash

1sh of all, we are talking about Debian/Ubuntu OS only.
(apologize if offended, because I'm only familiar with these 2)

2nd of all, we are talking about a non-root user with sudo privilege only.

---

Every time I'm going to run a command with sudo privilege, I always ask myself should I use `sudo bash -c 'command'` or just `sudo command`, it's kind of a pain for me.

And since that there are some situation that `sudo command` doesn't work directly, such as,
`sudo echo "smth" >> /etc/privilegedfile`

But it seems always work by using `sudo sh -c "echo 'smth' >> /etc/privilegedfile"` or `sudo bash -c "echo 'smth' >> /etc/privilegedfile"`

(or use another tool, like `tee` to make it work.)

---

So question is,

Is there any occasion(exception) that `sudo bash -c 'command'` is not capable to execute, but only `sudo command` can?

**is it a good idea to use `sudo bash -c` instead of `sudo` forever?**

Answer (score 12):

`sudo bash -c` and `sudo` are significantly different, because `sudo` can be configured to grant permissions to specific users running specific commands. You may therefore find yourself in a setup where you are allowed to run `sudo command` (for some value of `command`), but not `sudo bash`.

In general it’s a good idea to be as specific as possible, so favour `sudo command` over `sudo bash -c command`.

Answer (score 6):

Using `bash -c` with sudo can be significantly more dangerous than `sudo` alone. When running command at a shell, there are a lot of special characters that the shell handles and expands in various ways. For example `rm *.txt`, it is the shell (typically bash) you are typing that at that is expanding the *.txt into a list of files in the current folder ending in .txt. The sudo command, out of a desire for simplicity and security, does not do that. Instead, it just runs the command directly with exactly the arguments you pass to it. For example, let's say you run the following at a shell:

```
$ file=/etc/passwd
$ sudo vim $file
$ ls *.txt
hello.txt  world.txt
$ sudo rm *.txt
```

The first line sets a variable, `$file`, in your current shell, runs the sudo command as `sudo vim /etc/passwd`, then lists and sudo deletes all text files. It was the shell expanding that variable and filename wildcard before sudo ever had a chance to see it or run it. On that last line, when sudo was called, it saw it was given exactly three arguments, `rm`, `hello.txt`, and `world.txt`. It then called `rm` as user root with exactly two arguments with no further processing. If I used quotes around it like, say, `sudo rm "*.txt"`, then sudo would instead see and call the `rm` command with the one argument `*.txt`. The rm command would take that literally and try to delete a file called "*.txt" and find that it does not exist. It would not even look at the two other files that end in .txt. That expansion is done by the shell.

Just to drive the point home, when you take away the magic that the shell does to make live easier, the commands I listed above would have to be written directly without any variables or wildcard like this:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/passwd
$ ls hello.txt world.txt
hello.txt  world.txt
$ sudo rm hello.txt world.txt
```

None of the `ls`, `rm`, and `sudo` themselves know how to expand *.txt or `$file`, that's the shell's job. Now, let's look at where `bash -c` can be dangerous inside sudo. Please don't try this at home:

```
$ file=/etc/passwd
$ sudo vim $file
# Take a short break from your computer here...
$ file="/lets/be/malicious; cp /dev/zero /dev/sda"
$ sudo vim $file  # Might see a harmless error here
$ sudo bash -c "vim $file"  # Goodbye hard-drive
```

While I have to admit, this is a very contrived example, I hope it's not too hard to imagine some potential dangers that can occur here. The issue is that you are now giving the shell to expand meta-characters as root. Let's say you walked away and someone modified the file variable to embed a malicious command in it, one that will wipe your hard drive. With the former syntax of `sudo vim $file`, it will expand that as a regular, unprivileged user and fail. In the second usage, it will expand $file and all the magic embedded in it to run at a full-fledged shell run as root.